# c fgets duplicates last character

Tags: c, stdin, fgets

I am trying to read integer values from stdin. I have a inner while loop that detects integer series so that I can parse ints with multiple characters. I strtok the buffer with newline delimiters because input can have integers over multiple lines.

My code to handle this is:

```
while (fgets(buf, BUF_SIZE, stdin)) {
    strtok(buf, "\n");
    for(int i = 0; buf[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        size_t j = 0;
        if(isdigit(buf[i])) {
            while(isdigit(buf[i+(int)j])) {
                j++;
            }
            char *new_str = malloc(j*sizeof(char));
            size_t k =0;
            while(k < j) {
                new_str[k] = buf[i+(int)k];
                k++;
            }
            printf("%s\n", new_str);
            free(new_str);
        }
    }
}
```

The input could be:
1 9 10 10 11

The output should be:

```
1
9 
10 
10 
11
```

The output I get is:

```
1
9
10
0
10
0
11
1
```

So every last character of input with n>1 gets read twice by the buffer some way.

I am unsure how this is possible but can't figure it out.

Comment: No it does not get "read twice". Strings must be terminated with a `0`. Since you don't do that, printing such a string is wrong.

Comment: Also, you are not incrementing `i` when you are dealing with multi-digits in the first `while` loop.

Comment: you are using ``strtok()`` but not taking its result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does fgets() always null-terminate the string it returns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547061/does-fgets-always-null-terminate-the-string-it-returns)

Comment: I think also `malloc(j*sizeof(char));` should be `malloc(j + 1);` to allow for the terminator.

Comment: `strtok(buf, "\n");` --> fails to remove the `'\n'` when buffer is `"\n"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you grow `j` over the input string but you forget to grow `i` together with `j`.  So you grow `j` and after you print it, you will grow `i` by 1 from the last value, and that `i+1` will fall inside the input string that was already printed...

The solution is to reinitialize i so:

```
        if(isdigit(buf[i])) {
          .....
          free(new_str);
          i = i+j;
        }
```